# UITableViewEditingStyle with index 3 in Swift

Tags: swift, uitableview

the goal is to place radio buttons on each cell in table view. I don't want to use images for this.
Here [video lesson on youtube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=J0owoXImGV4) I found the undocumented possibility to do this in Objective-C.

So I did this in objc and it works. I tried to repeat this on Swift, but I can't found how to use this undocumented possibility )

Details:

the editing mode is used for adding this icon on the left side with following `[self.tableView setEditing:YES animated:YES];`

this method is used to set icon for editing mode:

```
- (UITableViewCellEditingStyle)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView editingStyleForRowAtIndexPath:(nonnull NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    return 3;
}
```

It's interesting though, that `UITableViewCellEditingStyle` as enum has only 3 values. Means you can return only values as `0`, `1` or `2`

```
typedef NS_ENUM(NSInteger, UITableViewCellEditingStyle) {
    UITableViewCellEditingStyleNone,
    UITableViewCellEditingStyleDelete,
    UITableViewCellEditingStyleInsert
};
```

But in example above the value `3` works. Works like a charm. 
[image: this is in obj-c]

How to do this in Swift? How to return value 3 for enum?
This is the enum example in Swift:

```
public enum UITableViewCellEditingStyle : Int {
    case None
    case Delete
    case Insert
}
```

Now I can return only predefined values from enum in Swift

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, editingStyleForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCellEditingStyle {
        return UITableViewCellEditingStyle.None
    }
```

But if try to return value `return UITableViewCellEditingStyle(rawValue: 3)!` - it does nothing.

Comment: Swift being strongly typed, I doubt you can do it. In Obj-C, enums were more like wrappers around Integers, In Swift they are first class types. So don't think compiler would let you do it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should not try this. It's a private API, so Apple's free to change it in a future version of iOS, breaking your app. Trying to use this private API is a bad, bad idea.

Here's how you could do it, if it weren't such a terrible idea, which it is:

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, editingStyleForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCellEditingStyle {
    return unsafeBitCast(3, UITableViewCellEditingStyle.self)
}
```

Comment: It started working. Thanks a lot! I guess I disabled the `self.tableView.setEditing(true, animated: true)` code by mistake )

Comment: Shouldn't this have the same result as `UITableViewCellEditingStyle(rawValue: 3)`?  I'm not saying your answer is wrong (it's a great answer), but it's weird that the `rawValue` initializer didn't work for the OP, since `UITableViewCellEditingStyle(rawValue: 3) == unsafeBitCast(3, UITableViewCellEditingStyle.self)` evaluates to `true`.

Comment: In Swift, an enum's initializer returns an Optional which is nil if the raw value doesn't correspond to a defined case.

Comment: @robmayoff but `UITableViewCellEditingStyle(rawValue: 3)` does not return nil.

Comment: You're right, it doesn't. I guess because it is defined in Objective-C and bridged to Swift, the constructor never fails.

Comment: Thanks Rob for the explanation. I've been confusing myself because I couldn't find a value of 3 in the enum of `UITableViewCellEditingStyle` in Swift. is there any way to implement this? How do we know if one is a private API?